# What values can be used in NSFont.TextStyleOptionKey

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsfont, dynamic-type-feature

I haven't been able to find valid values for [`NSFont.TextStyleOptionKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/textstyleoptionkey).

More specifically I want to use [`NSFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/3553195-preferredfont) to have dynamic (dynamic point size) type, but I would like to change the weight of the font.

Comment: Got any answers for this? @vauxhall

Comment: @ohmprakash As of macOS 12 (Xcode 13.2.1) there seems to be no way of using this yet. My uneducated guess is that this just for getting ready to an upcoming update concerning TextKit 2 (announced on WWDC 21 but still with very little adoption, mainly only iOS so far).

Comment: I would assume this is for options like the font design i.e. monospaced. But it is still nowhere to be found.